# is signal periodic or not? using MATLAB functions possible?

Tags: matlab

Briefly explain the reason for the (non)periodicity of a signal using MATLAB functions

like isperiodic(signal) ...

any thing like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[fft](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fft.html) can do it:

```
Y = fft(signal);
periodLength = 'second'; %or whatever units your signal was acquired in.
N = length(Y);
Y(1) = [];
power = abs(Y(1:floor(N/2))).^2;
nyquist = 1/2;
freq = (1:floor(N/2))/floor(N/2)*nyquist;
figure;
plot(freq,power)
grid on
xlabel(['cycles/' periodLength]);
title('Frequency plot');
```

and this gives it as number of periods per cycle.

```
period = 1./freq;
figure;
plot(period,power)
grid on
ylabel('Power')
xlabel(['Period (' periodLength 's/Cycle)']);
title('Period Plot');
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into the concept of [autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) of a signal, ([XCORR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/xcorr.html) function in MATLAB)